# Append <br> using d3

Tags: dom, d3.js

I am using d3 to create a series of radioboxes. I would like them each to be on their own line, so I want to put a `<br>` tag after each one. Basically, I'm looking for code that will produce this:

`<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="">
    some text
 </label>
 <br>`

This is my code:

`function addradiobox() {
       d3.select(container) //container is the div element where the boxes will go
                .append("label")          //label for radiobox
                .text(text)
                .append("input")          //radiobox
                .attr("type","checkbox")
                .attr("value", "")
                .style("float","left")   //move box left of label
                .append("br");
}`

Its output is what I want except for no `<br>` tag, so when I call the function a second time the second radiobox is on the same line as the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are appending the `<br>` to the `<input>` element, which cannot have child elements. Each time you use `.append()`, you return a selection of the element that was appended. In your case, you used `.append('input')` and then tried to `.append('br')` to the input, like this:

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="" style="float: left;">
    <br>
  </input>
  some text
</label>
```

Which doesn't make sense.

You can re-select the container before appending the `br` and then you will append it as a sibling to the label:

```
d3.select(container)
  .append('label')
  .text(text)
  .append('input')
    .attr('type', 'checkbox')
    .attr('value', '')
    .style('float', 'left');
d3.select(container)
  .append('br');
```

This should give you the output you were hoping for.

Comment: another solution could have been to style them with clear:left; so each would have been on a different row